# setAttribute onClick function - React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have 2 functions - addBookmark() and removeBookmark.

I have vaiable IsBookmakred that is true or false. Part of my JSX containing bookmark is:

```
  {props.singleCompany.IsBookmarked ? (
      <div>
        <span
          className="fa fa-star bookmarked"
          onClick={removeBookmark}
          data-tip="Remove Bookmark"
        ></span>
        <ReactTooltip />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <span
          className="fa fa-star"
          onClick={addBookmark}
          data-tip="Add Bookmark"
        ></span>
        <ReactTooltip />
      </div>
    )}
```

As you see I am using both functions addBookmark nad removeBookmark as per situation. I need to be able to change this  attributes if bookmark is true or false (when it is clicked). Here is 1 of my functions for example without POST request:

```
    const addBookmark = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    const data = {
      userGuid: sessionStorage.getItem("Guid"),

      smallPlanID: props.singleCompany.SmallCompanyPlanID,

      largePlanID: props.singleCompany.LargeCompanyPlanID
    };
    e.target.classList.add("bookmarked");
    e.target.onclick = removeBookmark();

    //POST REQUEST IS HERE...
  };
```

As you can see  e.target.onclick = removeBookmark(); is not the thing I want. This is just to show my idea what has to happen. I tried:

```
e.target('onclick','doSomething();');
```

also but without success. How should I change my onClick attribute to point to other function?

Comment: How about a `toggleBookmark` method instead of `addBookmark`/`removeBookmark` that checks the current statebefore making corresponding requests?

Comment: This is idea that can resolve problem in this task but I still want to know how to perform the onclick attribute change.

Comment: AFAIR, React uses wrappers around native events to provide synthetic events. I also believe that is uses `addEventListener` for listening to native events. If that's true, replacing the listener with vanilla JS might require some ugly code, not sure if that's OK to use for any production code.

Comment: Just got an idea - I can change IsBookmarked in each function instead of changing attributes.

Comment: I thought that was a given since you relied on it for displaying the corresponding button.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov Are you using hooks or classes ?

Comment: @Fraction hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state `isBookmarked` and use it like this:

```
const [isBookmarked, setIsBookmarked] = useState(props.singleCompany.IsBookmarked);

const addBookmark = e => {
  ...
  setIsBookmarked(!isBookmarked)
}

const removeBookmark = e => {
  ...
  setIsBookmarked(!isBookmarked)
}

...
<div>
  <span
    className=`fa fa-star ${isBookmarked ? 'bookmarked' : ''}`
    onClick={isBookmarked ? removeBookmark : addBookmark}
    data-tip={isBookmarked ? 'Remove Bookmark' : 'Add Bookmark'}
  ></span>
  <ReactTooltip />
</div>
```